# Why glpk sees a linear programming formulation as a nonlinear programming?

Tags: python, pyomo, glpk

I'm new to both Python and Pyomo. Nonetheless, I've made the below code following my previous question. However, if I run it using glpk solver, it says

> RuntimeError: Cannot write legal LP file.  Objective 'cost' has nonlinear terms that are not quadratic.

I think the formulation is an LP. I'm guessing it is the calculation of parameter "demandsperyear"? But, it shouldn't be the cause as it is a parameter, not a variable, right?

If i use cbc, I've got errors that I cannot understand.

```
from pyomo.environ import *
m = AbstractModel() 

m.techs = Set()
m.products = Set()
m.suppliers = Set()
m.demands = Set()
m.years = Set()

m.initial_demands = Param(m.demands,m.products)
m.growths = Param(m.demands,m.products)
m.yields = Param(m.techs,m.products,m.suppliers)
m.CO2emissions = Param(m.techs,m.suppliers)
m.TAC = Param(m.techs,m.suppliers)
m.max_installed = Param(m.techs,m.suppliers)

m.installed_techs = Var(m.techs, m.suppliers, m.years, within=Binary)
m.number_installed_techs= Var(m.techs, m.suppliers, m.years, bounds=(0,None))
m.totalTAC = Var(bounds=(None,None))
m.totalCO2 = Var(bounds=(None,None))
m.totalTACperyear = Var(m.years, bounds=(None, None))
m.totalCO2peryear = Var(m.years, bounds=(None, None))

def total_TAC(m):
    return m.totalTAC == sum(m.totalTACperyear[year] for year in m.years)
m.cost = Objective(rule=total_TAC, sense=minimize)

def total_CO2(m):
    return m.totalCO2 == sum(m.totalCO2peryear[year] for year in m.years)
m.totalCO2_cons = Constraint(rule=total_CO2)

def total_TACperyear(m,year):
    return m.totalTACperyear[year] == sum(m.number_installed_techs[tech,supplier,year]*m.TAC[tech,supplier] for tech in m.techs for supplier in m.suppliers)

m.TACperyear_cons = Constraint(m.years, rule=total_TACperyear)

def total_CO2peryear(m,year):
    return m.totalCO2peryear[year] == sum(m.number_installed_techs[tech,supplier,year]*m.CO2emissions[tech,supplier] for tech in m.techs for supplier in m.suppliers) 

m.CO2peryear_cons = Constraint(m.years, rule=total_CO2peryear)

def demandperyear(m,demand,product,year):
    if year == 1:
        expression = m.initial_demands[demand,product]
        return expression
    expression = m.initial_demands[demand,product]*(1 + m.growths[demand,product]*year)
    return expression

m.demandsperyear = Param(m.demands, m.products,m.years, initialize=demandperyear)

def fulfill_demands(m,supplier,demand,product,year):
    if supplier == demand:
        expression = sum(m.number_installed_techs[tech,supplier,year]*m.yields[tech,product,supplier] for tech in m.techs) >= m.demandsperyear[demand,product,year]
        return expression
    return Constraint.Skip

m.fulfill_demands_cons = Constraint(m.suppliers,m.demands,m.products,m.years, rule=fulfill_demands)

def max_installed(m,tech,supplier):
    expression = sum(m.number_installed_techs[tech,supplier,year] for year in m.years) <= m.max_installed[tech,supplier]
    return expression

m.max_installed_cons = Constraint(m.techs,m.suppliers, rule=max_installed)

def accum_installed(m,tech,supplier,year):
    if year == 1:
        expression = m.number_installed_techs[tech,supplier,year] == m.installed_techs[tech,supplier,year]
        return expression
    expression = m.number_installed_techs[tech,supplier,year] == m.number_installed_techs[tech,supplier,year-1] + m.installed_techs[tech,supplier,year]
    return expression

m.accum_cons = Constraint(m.techs,m.suppliers,m.years, rule=accum_installed)

# parameter
data = {None: {
    'techs' : {None: ['tek_A', 'tek_B', 'tek_C']},
    'products' : {None: ['prod_A', 'prod_B', 'prod_C']},
    'suppliers' : {None: ['daerah_A', 'daerah_B', 'daerah_C']},
    'demands' : {None: ['daerah_A', 'daerah_B', 'daerah_C']},
    'years' : {None: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7,8,9,10]},
    'initial_demands': {('daerah_A','prod_A'): 10.0, ('daerah_A','prod_B'): 10.0, ('daerah_A','prod_C'): 10.0,
                        ('daerah_B','prod_A'): 20.0, ('daerah_B','prod_B'): 20.0, ('daerah_B','prod_C'): 20.0,
                        ('daerah_C','prod_A'): 12.0, ('daerah_C','prod_B'): 12.0, ('daerah_C','prod_C'): 12.0},
    'growths': {('daerah_A','prod_A'): 0.02, ('daerah_A','prod_B'): 0.02, ('daerah_A','prod_C'): 0.02,
                        ('daerah_B','prod_A'): 0.02, ('daerah_B','prod_B'): 0.02, ('daerah_B','prod_C'): 0.02,
                        ('daerah_C','prod_A'): 0.02, ('daerah_C','prod_B'): 0.02, ('daerah_C','prod_C'): 0.02},
    'max_installed' : {('tek_A','daerah_A'): 100.0, ('tek_A','daerah_B'): 100.0, ('tek_A','daerah_C'): 100.0,
                        ('tek_B','daerah_A'): 100.0, ('tek_B','daerah_B'): 100.0, ('tek_B','daerah_C'): 100.0,
                        ('tek_C','daerah_A'): 100.0, ('tek_C','daerah_B'): 100.0, ('tek_C','daerah_C'): 100.0},
    'TAC' : {('tek_A','daerah_A'): 100.0, ('tek_A','daerah_B'): 100.0, ('tek_A','daerah_C'): 100.0,
                        ('tek_B','daerah_A'): 100.0, ('tek_B','daerah_B'): 100.0, ('tek_B','daerah_C'): 100.0,
                        ('tek_C','daerah_A'): 100.0, ('tek_C','daerah_B'): 100.0, ('tek_C','daerah_C'): 100.0},
    'CO2emissions' : {('tek_A','daerah_A'): 20.0, ('tek_A','daerah_B'): 20.0, ('tek_A','daerah_C'): 20.0,
                        ('tek_B','daerah_A'): 20.0, ('tek_B','daerah_B'): 20.0, ('tek_B','daerah_C'): 20.0,
                        ('tek_C','daerah_A'): 20.0, ('tek_C','daerah_B'): 20.0, ('tek_C','daerah_C'): 20.0},
    'yields': {('tek_A','prod_A','daerah_A'):8.0, ('tek_A','prod_A','daerah_B'):8.0, ('tek_A','prod_A','daerah_C'):8.0,
                    ('tek_A','prod_B','daerah_A'):8.0, ('tek_A','prod_B','daerah_B'):8.0, ('tek_A','prod_B','daerah_C'):8.0,
                    ('tek_A','prod_C','daerah_A'):8.0, ('tek_A','prod_C','daerah_B'):8.0, ('tek_A','prod_C','daerah_C'):8.0,
                    ('tek_B','prod_A','daerah_A'):8.0, ('tek_B','prod_A','daerah_B'):8.0, ('tek_B','prod_A','daerah_C'):8.0,
                    ('tek_B','prod_B','daerah_A'):8.0, ('tek_B','prod_B','daerah_B'):8.0, ('tek_B','prod_B','daerah_C'):8.0,
                    ('tek_B','prod_C','daerah_A'):8.0, ('tek_B','prod_C','daerah_B'):8.0, ('tek_B','prod_C','daerah_C'):8.0,
                    ('tek_C','prod_A','daerah_A'):8.0, ('tek_C','prod_A','daerah_B'):8.0, ('tek_C','prod_A','daerah_C'):8.0,
                    ('tek_C','prod_B','daerah_A'):8.0, ('tek_C','prod_B','daerah_B'):8.0, ('tek_C','prod_B','daerah_C'):8.0,
                    ('tek_C','prod_C','daerah_A'):8.0, ('tek_C','prod_C','daerah_B'):8.0, ('tek_C','prod_C','daerah_C'):8.0}
    }}

instance = m.create_instance(data)
instance.pprint()

solver = SolverFactory('glpk')
hasil = solver.solve(instance)

for tech in instance.installed_techs.values():
    print(tech.value)

for number_of_techs_installed in instance.number_installed_techs.values():
    print(number_of_techs_installed.value)

for TACperyear in instance.totalTACperyear.values():
    print(TACperyear.value)

for CO2peryear in instance.totalCO2peryear.values():
    print(CO2peryear.value)

print('Total TAC', instance.totalTAC())
print('Total CO2', instance.totalCO2())
```

If I have to calculate the "demandsperyear" outside of the Pyomo, how should i do that?

Thanks

Comment: `m.totalTAC == sum(m.totalTACperyear[year] for year in m.years)` is boolean, not linear.

Comment: With your code I get: `ValueError: Cannot assign EqualityExpression to 'cost'`. Apparently you are trying to minimize the total TAC but it's a given value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get something I had to solve, as @user2357112 suggested, the problem on `total_TAC`:

```
def total_TAC(m):
    # return m.totalTAC == sum(m.totalTACperyear[year] for year in m.years)
    return sum(m.totalTACperyear[year] for year in m.years)
```

Then I calculated `demandsperyear` before creating the instance:

```
def demandperyear_outside(demand, product, year, initial_demands, growths):
    if year == 1:
        return initial_demands[demand, product]
    # I assume compound growth for the next years, maybe you want to change this
    return initial_demands[demand, product] * (1 + growths[demand, product] * year)

demandsperyear_data = {
  (demand, product, year): demandperyear_outside(
    demand, product, year, data[None]['initial_demands'], data[None]['growths']) 
    for demand in data[None]['demands'][None] 
    for product in data[None]['products'][None] 
    for year in data[None]['years'][None]
}
```

which I add to the `data`:

```
data[None]['demandsperyear'] = demandsperyear_data
```

With this I change your `m.demandsperyear` to:

```
m.demandsperyear = Param(m.demands, m.products, m.years, initialize=data[None]['demandsperyear'])
```

I'm getting a **Total CO2** (1400) but sadly a `None` for **Total TAC**.

**Update for my second attempt**: I added a constraint for `totalTAC` as follows:

```
def total_TAC_constraint(m):
    return m.totalTAC == sum(m.totalTACperyear[year] for year in m.years)

m.totalTAC_cons = Constraint(rule=total_TAC_constraint)
```

and I'm now getting results:

```
Total TAC 7000.0
Total CO2 1400.0
```

Comment: By the way, what does it mean by adding **data[None]** as in your additional code? When changing the **m.demandsperyear** above, it says that **data** is not defined.

Comment: I did this because the original `dict` with data was like `data = {None: {...}}`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code as posted has nothing to do with linear/nonlinear.  The problem is in your objective function.  Your objective function (below) is written as an **equality**, as you would in a constraint.

```
def total_TAC(m):
    return m.totalTAC == sum(m.totalTACperyear[year] for year in m.years)
m.cost = Objective(rule=total_TAC, sense=minimize)
```

The objective function should be an expression of the variables that is, well, variable.  If you substitute in this, all works.  Of course, I don't know if this is the mathematical formulation you are looking for in your model, over to you on that.  This just minimizes the sum as the objective.

```
def total_TAC(m):
    return sum(m.totalTACperyear[year] for year in m.years)
m.cost = Objective(rule=total_TAC, sense=minimize)
```